# NServiceBus or Rhino Service Bus or anything else?

Tags: .net, wcf, soa, distributed

In your opinion and feedback from people and forum, which one do you think is good and has more success stories for a .NET based winform,wcf,sql combination application.

I am new to SOA arena and looking to employ a message bus solution for our new project.

Thanks,
mani

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is to confirm if / why you need a service bus.

Unless you have a real need it will just make your project more complicated and more expensive.

Comment: well, pls assume it is needed.

Comment: My point was that you can use a service bus pattern without a service bus product.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any standard implementations available or any framework already built for this. I am assuming if not using a product, things like this take a while to be built.

Comment: You can use Phoenix Service Bus: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/ It is free to use and has lot of examples to get started: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples%2fExamples&referringTitle=Home. It also have documentation: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/documentation and performance information too: http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Performance%20Result&referringTitle=Home